# Kendo UI Databound object not updating when derived member with function

Tags: kendo-ui

I have an observable that has two derived members that in turn use a function to manipulate the values from the main data. Simple functions, that do a little string manipulation.

When first loaded and bound to a DOM fragment, it all works fine, but if I then update the values, the derived value does not change.

```
//mvvm
window.userdata = kendo.observable({
    user: null,
    miniavatar: function () { return getAvatarUriWithRadius(this.get('user.AvatarPublicId'), 36); },
});

//first bind which works
$.post('Account/GetUser', {}, function(response) {
    window.userdata.set('user', response.Data);

    //bind the notifications and overduetasks
    kendo.bind($('#top'), window.userdata.user);

});


//DOM
<div id="top">
    <div id="latesthig" class="floatright">
        <div data-bind="attr:{class:latesthigclass}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="button floatright"><a id="search" href="#"></a></div>

    <span class="button" id="addnote" title="add note"><span></span></span>
    <span data-bind="text:miniavatar"></span>

    <div id="messages"></div>

</div>
```

Subsequent change of value which doesn't change the text from the miniavatar derived member

```
window.userdata.set('user.AvatarPublicId', value);
```

Any thoughts anyone? Silly mistake somewhere?
TIA

Comment: It should be noted that getAvatarUriWithRadius has a global scope. That function is not even being triggered when the values are changed.

Comment: What is Account/GetUser returning? as far as I can see is a `string`, how do you access `response.Data`?

Comment: We have a Jsonwrapper that we return all out data in - so response is always a Json object with teh paylod in Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding to the `User` sub property of the observable instead of the observable itself.

Change your binding code to bind to the observable:

```
kendo.bind($('#top'), window.userdata);
```

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARGH.

Comment: Not seeing wood for trees. Why was it working ok on the first bind though? Hmm.